# Which force is responsible for $\Sigma$(1385) decay?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, baryons

I was looking at the excited state of the $\Sigma^+$, the $\Sigma^{*+}(1385)$, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_baryon). I was wondering which forces are responsible for its two most dominant decays

$$ \Sigma^{*+}(1385) \to \Lambda^0 \pi^+$$
$$ \Sigma^{*+}(1385) \to \Sigma^0 \pi^+ $$

Here’s my attempt:

For the first decay, isospin, strangeness and parity are conserved. Therefore it is strong process. Is my reasoning correct?

For the second decay, isospin is not conserved ($\Sigma^{*+}$ has isospin $1$ while both $\Sigma^0$ and $\pi^+$ have isospins of $1$ as well), parity is conserved. Therefore this is an EM process. Is my reasoning correct? Does an EM decay not need to have emitted photons?

Comment: Isospin is also conserved for the second decay. Where did you imagine a violation? The pion is an isovector. Did you compose isospins right? Both decays are strong, as you may check from their widths. Not EM!

Comment: @CosmasZachos The initial $\Sigma^{*+}$ has isospin 1. Both $\Sigma^0$ and $\pi^+$ have isospin 1. Can we compose two isospins 1 to get a total isospin of 1? Unless I am mistaken, that is not possible. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are mistaken. Do the Clebsches. A cross product is a (pseudo)vector. That's what you are missing.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I see it now, thank you so much!